# Socket programming MEAN stack, Express app on port 3000 and Angular app on 8000

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, express, amazon-ec2

I am trying to make a socket application using MEAN stack and socket.io. I want to setup my Express app on one port (say 3000) and Angular app on another port (say 8000).

Later I will try to move my Express on EC2 and Angular app on S3.

**Is this kind of setup possible?**

I have found many examples where front-end (Angular app) is served by Express like this.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 });
```

But I don't want this, I want my separate front-end which is able to connect to back-end (Express) using **sockets**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this setup is completely possible.

You just have to create a websocket server (using Socket.io for example) that you attach to you express server.

And on the other side, in Angular, connect to this websocket server. 
For example using [angular-websocket](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket) :

```
var wsUrl = 'ws://yourdomain.com:[YOUR_EXPRESS_APP_PORT]/';
var dataStream = $websocket(wsUrl);
dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
    // do something here
});
```